# Implement two filters in one condition - SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a report. In that I am displaying total no of leads, leads sent via Fax and Leads sent via SMS. I wrote a procedure to fetch the records . Here I have to check an condition that both Leads sent via SMS and Leads sent via Fax should not be zero. If both are zero I should not fetch the record. If one of them has any value i should fetch the record. Is it possible implement it through SQL Query.

FROM OP comment to astander

```
SELECT  C.ClientID ,
        C.ClientName ,
        C.OrganizationName,
        C.FirstName ,
        S.SMSOverageRate ,
        '' as Cost ,
        Count(*) as TotalLeads ,
        Sum(CASE DeliveryViaFax WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FaxCount ,
        Sum(CASE DeliveryViaSMSEmail WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SMSCount 
FROM    CMN_LeadSaleDetails S INNER JOIN 
        CMN_LeadClients C ON C.ClientID = S.BuyerID 
WHERE   C.SellerTenantId = @TenantId 
AND     S.SellerJournalID = CASE @JournalId WHEN 0 THEN S.SellerJournalID ELSE @JournalId END 
GROUP BY C.ClientID ,
        C.ClientName ,
        C.OrganizationName,
        C.FirstName ,
        S.SMSOverageRate
```

Comment: Yes it is, but to give you a more detailed answer that will really hellp you, would you mind sharing the code you have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (TotalSMSLeads != 0
OR TotalFaxLeads != 0)
```

Provide the example query and we can assist you further.

OK, from what you commented i would try something like this

```
SELECT  C.ClientID ,
        C.ClientName ,
        C.OrganizationName,
        C.FirstName ,
        S.SMSOverageRate ,
        '' as Cost ,
        Count(*) as TotalLeads ,
        Sum(CASE DeliveryViaFax WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FaxCount ,
        Sum(CASE DeliveryViaSMSEmail WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SMSCount 
FROM    CMN_LeadSaleDetails S INNER JOIN 
        CMN_LeadClients C ON C.ClientID = S.BuyerID 
WHERE   C.SellerTenantId = @TenantId 
AND     S.SellerJournalID = CASE @JournalId WHEN 0 THEN S.SellerJournalID ELSE @JournalId END 
GROUP BY C.ClientID ,
        C.ClientName ,
        C.OrganizationName,
        C.FirstName ,
        S.SMSOverageRate
HAVING  (   Sum(CASE DeliveryViaFax WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) != 0
        OR  Sum(CASE DeliveryViaSMSEmail WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) != 0)
```

Comment: C.ClientID
,C.ClientName
,C.OrganizationName
C.FirstName
,S.SMSOverageRate
,'' as Cost
,Count(*) as TotalLeads
,Sum(CASE DeliveryViaFax WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FaxCount
,Sum(CASE DeliveryViaSMSEmail WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SMSCount
FROM CMN_LeadSaleDetails S
INNER JOIN CMN_LeadClients C ON C.ClientID = S.BuyerID
WHERE C.SellerTenantId = @TenantId 
AND S.SellerJournalID = CASE @JournalId WHEN 0 THEN  S.SellerJournalID  ELSE @JournalId

This is my sample query. I have to check both Fax count and SMS count should not be zero

Comment: You win, yours is much neater.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively..

```
Select *
From TABLE
Where (SMSLeads + FaxLeads) > 0
```

Using your SQL

```
Select C.ClientID ,C.ClientName ,C.OrganizationName 
C.FirstName ,S.SMSOverageRate ,'' as Cost,
Count(*) as TotalLeads ,
Sum(CASE DeliveryViaFax WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FaxCount ,
Sum(CASE DeliveryViaSMSEmail WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SMSCount
```

`FROM CMN_LeadSaleDetails S 
    INNER JOIN CMN_LeadClients C 
        ON C.ClientID = S.BuyerID 
WHERE   C.SellerTenantId = @TenantId 
AND S.SellerJournalID = CASE @JournalId WHEN 0 THEN S.SellerJournalID ELSE @JournalId
Group By C.ClientID ,C.ClientName ,C.OrganizationName 
    C.FirstName ,S.SMSOverageRate
Having (FaxCount+SMSCount) > 0`

Comment: HI leigh-shayler,
I am getting faxleads and SMS leads value using aggregate function. How can I achieve it in this condition